# Simplist script for day-before-yesterday

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

Is this the simplist way to find the day-before-yesterday?

```
TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day].MEMBERS,1).item(0).lag(1)
```

Comment: If the last member of your Calendar Day level is Yesterday, then yes, I believe it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example this will not work if your last member of calendar is not yesterday!
The below will always give you day before yesterday:

the part ( Now()-2 ) - this is the offset from current system time in days.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Yesterday] AS VBAMDX.Format(VBAMDX.Now()-2,"MM-dd-yyyy")
SELECT [Measures].[Yesterday] ON COLUMNS 
FROM
[Cube]
```